# Need to capture a still image during face detection with MLKit and Camera2

Tags: android, face-detection, android-camera2, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm developing a **Face Detection** feature with **Camera2** and **MLKit**.

In the Developer Guide, in the [Performance Tips](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces#performance_tips) part, they say to capture images in `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` format if using the Camera2 API, which is my case.

Then, in the [Face Detector](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces#2-run-the-face-detector) part, they recommend to use an image with dimensions of at least 480x360 pixels for faces recognition in real time, which is again my case.

Ok, let's go ! Here is my code, working well

```
private fun initializeCamera() = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

    // Open the selected camera
    cameraDevice = openCamera(cameraManager, getCameraId(), cameraHandler)

    val previewSize = if (isPortrait) {
        Size(RECOMMANDED_CAPTURE_SIZE.width, RECOMMANDED_CAPTURE_SIZE.height)
    } else {
        Size(RECOMMANDED_CAPTURE_SIZE.height, RECOMMANDED_CAPTURE_SIZE.width)
    }

    // Initialize an image reader which will be used to display a preview
    imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
            previewSize.width, previewSize.height, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE)

    // Retrieve preview's frame and run detector
    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val image = reader.acquireNextImage()
            logD { "Image available: ${image.timestamp}" }
            faceDetector.runFaceDetection(image, getRotationCompensation())
            image.close()
        }
    }, imageReaderHandler)

    // Creates list of Surfaces where the camera will output frames
    val targets = listOf(viewfinder.holder.surface, imageReader.surface)

    // Start a capture session using our open camera and list of Surfaces where frames will go
    session = createCaptureSession(cameraDevice, targets, cameraHandler)
    val captureRequest = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(
            CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW).apply {
        addTarget(viewfinder.holder.surface)
        addTarget(imageReader.surface)
    }

    // This will keep sending the capture request as frequently as possible until the
    // session is torn down or session.stopRepeating() is called
    session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest.build(), null, cameraHandler)
}
```

Now, I want to capture a still image...and this is my problem because, ideally, I want:

- a full resolution image or, as least, bigger than 480x360
- in JPEG format to be able to save it

The [Camera2Basic sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples) demonstrates how to capture an image (samples for Video and SlowMotion are crashing) and [MLKit sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) uses the so old Camera API !!  Fortunately, I've succeeded is mixing these samples to develop my feature but I'm failed to capture a **still image** with a different resolution.

I think I have to stop the preview session to recreate one for image capture but I'm not sure...

What I have done is the following but it's capturing images in 480x360:

```
session.stopRepeating()

 // Unset the image reader listener
 imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null)
 // Initialize an new image reader which will be used to capture still photos
 // imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(768, 1024, ImageFormat.JPEG, IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE)

 // Start a new image queue
 val imageQueue = ArrayBlockingQueue<Image>(IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE)
 imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader - >
    val image = reader.acquireNextImage()
    logD {"[Still] Image available in queue: ${image.timestamp}"}
    if (imageQueue.size >= IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE - 1) {
        imageQueue.take().close()
    }
    imageQueue.add(image)
}, imageReaderHandler)

 // Creates list of Surfaces where the camera will output frames
 val targets = listOf(viewfinder.holder.surface, imageReader.surface)
 val captureRequest = createStillCaptureRequest(cameraDevice, targets)
 session.capture(captureRequest, object: CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    override fun onCaptureCompleted(
        session: CameraCaptureSession,
        request: CaptureRequest,
        result: TotalCaptureResult) {
        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)
        val resultTimestamp = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP)
        logD {"Capture result received: $resultTimestamp"}
        // Set a timeout in case image captured is dropped from the pipeline
        val exc = TimeoutException("Image dequeuing took too long")
        val timeoutRunnable = Runnable {
            continuation.resumeWithException(exc)
        }
        imageReaderHandler.postDelayed(timeoutRunnable, IMAGE_CAPTURE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
        // Loop in the coroutine's context until an image with matching timestamp comes
        // We need to launch the coroutine context again because the callback is done in
        //  the handler provided to the `capture` method, not in our coroutine context
        @ Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
        lifecycleScope.launch(continuation.context) {
            while (true) {
                // Dequeue images while timestamps don't match
                val image = imageQueue.take()
                if (image.timestamp != resultTimestamp)
                  continue
                logD {"Matching image dequeued: ${image.timestamp}"}

                // Unset the image reader listener
                imageReaderHandler.removeCallbacks(timeoutRunnable)
                imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null)

                // Clear the queue of images, if there are left
                while (imageQueue.size > 0) {
                    imageQueue.take()
                        .close()
                }
                // Compute EXIF orientation metadata
                val rotation = getRotationCompensation()
                val mirrored = cameraFacing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                val exifOrientation = computeExifOrientation(rotation, mirrored)
                logE {"captured image size (w/h): ${image.width} / ${image.height}"}
                // Build the result and resume progress
                continuation.resume(CombinedCaptureResult(
                    image, result, exifOrientation, imageReader.imageFormat))
                // There is no need to break out of the loop, this coroutine will suspend
            }
        }
    }
}, cameraHandler)
}
```

If I uncomment the new ImageReader instanciation, I have this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CaptureRequest contains
>   unconfigured Input/Output Surface!

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: `Camera 2` is a royal pain in the ass. `Camera X` seems promising because of the image analizer as @Martin pointed out. If you want to enjoy your life, please consider using `CameraView` https://github.com/natario1/CameraView you should be up and running with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This `IllegalArgumentException`:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CaptureRequest contains unconfigured Input/Output Surface!

... obviously refers to `imageReader.surface`.

---

Meanhile (with CameraX) this works different, see [CameraFragment.kt](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L265) ...

Issue #197: [Firebase Face Detection Api issue while using cameraX API](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/197);

there might soon be a sample application matching your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I will check this. But, for operational reasons, I don't want to use CameraX since `PreviewView` is in alpha. And yes, the Exception refers to imageReader...but why ?

Answer (score 0):

ImageReader is sensitive to the choice of format and/or combination of usage flags. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader#newInstance(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20long)) points certain combinations of format may be unsupported. With some Android devices (perhaps some older phone models) you might find the `IllegalArgumentException` is not thrown using the JPEG format. But it doesn't help much - you want something versatile.

What I have done in the past is to use `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` format (this will be backed by the hardware and ImageReader implementation). This format does not contain pre-optimizations that prevent the application accessing the image via the internal array of planes. I notice you have used it successfully already in your `initializeCamera()` method.

You may then extract the image data from the frame you want

```
Image.Plane[] planes = img.getPlanes();
byte[] data = planes[0].getBuffer().array();
```

and then via a Bitmap create the still image using JPEG compression, PNG, or whichever encoding you choose.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, out);
byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
ByteArrayOutputStream out2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, out2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but how to capture a frame in a different resolution ? It can surely be possible to capture a frame bigger than 480x360 pixels, but I don't know how...

Comment: There is more than one approach to creating a scaled Bitmap from an original Bitmap. Would that be sufficient? Depending on the method, it can sometimes be a bottleneck when performance is key. Or is the question specifically about ImageReader?

Comment: I don't want to upscale the 480x360 image, I want to capture an image bigger and in another format

Comment: Yes surely ImageReader supports larger than  480x360 pixels. But for reasons provided you should use the appropriate format and then convert to the output format you require.